# restore from differential backup file to a new server with multiple files

Tags: sql-server

Could not found a clear answer online. Please advise. Thanks

I was going to restore sql server 2008 db from production backup (full and diff) to a new server. The db has 20 data files and 1 log file. I got the full restore script correct with all MOVE options specified in the script. Question is do I need to specify the MOVE options for all the data files again? or simply do this:

RESTORE DATABASE [mydb]
FROM  DISK=N'\backupshare\mydb_20131021220215.DIF' WITH  RECOVERY

Answer (score 2):

Tested it myself and turned out you do not need to specify MOVE clause again in restoring differential backup files if that's already done when restoring full backup file. It works too though if you do MOVE again. So, does not really matter, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Restore your data base with the last `Full-Backup` `WITH NO RECOVERY` 
then Restore the `Differential Backup` using `WITH RECOVERY`

Comment: In restoring full backup, I specified MOVE option to move 20 data files to new location (new server/path). My question is do I need to do the same (MOVE) for the differential restore. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe helpful for restoring database from full + differential backup: https://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/08/18/ssms-how-to-restore-differential-backups/